# Public Main() method is required in a public class

Tags: c#

I am getting:

> Public Main() method is required in a public class

error when I am running this script:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
 public static void Main(string[] args) {

    //Shared 256 bit Key and IV here
    const string sKy = "lkirwf897+22#bbtrm8814z5qq=498j5"; //32 chr shared ascii string (32 * 8 = 256 bit)
    const string sIV = "741952hheeyy66#cs!9hjv887mxx7@8y"; //32 chr shared ascii string (32 * 8 = 256 bit)

    var sTextVal = "Here is my data to encrypt!!!";

    var eText = EncryptRJ256(sKy, sIV, sTextVal);
    var dText = DecryptRJ256(sKy, sIV, eText);

    Console.WriteLine("key: " + sKy);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(" iv: " + sIV);
    Console.WriteLine("txt: " + sTextVal);
    Console.WriteLine("encrypted: " + eText);
    Console.WriteLine("decrypted: " + dText);
    Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
  }

  public static string DecryptRJ256(string prm_key, string prm_iv, string prm_text_to_decrypt) {

    var sEncryptedString = prm_text_to_decrypt;

    var myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged() {
      Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros,
      Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
      KeySize = 256,
      BlockSize = 256
    };

    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(prm_key);
    var IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(prm_iv);

    var decryptor = myRijndael.CreateDecryptor(key, IV);

    var sEncrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(sEncryptedString);

    var fromEncrypt = new byte[sEncrypted.Length];

    var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(sEncrypted);
    var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    csDecrypt.Read(fromEncrypt, 0, fromEncrypt.Length);

    return (Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fromEncrypt));
  }

  public static string EncryptRJ256(string prm_key, string prm_iv, string prm_text_to_encrypt) {

    var sToEncrypt = prm_text_to_encrypt;

    var myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged() {
      Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros,
      Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
      KeySize = 256,
      BlockSize = 256
    };

    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(prm_key);
    var IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(prm_iv);

    var encryptor = myRijndael.CreateEncryptor(key, IV);

    var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
    var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    var toEncrypt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sToEncrypt);

    csEncrypt.Write(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);
    csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();

    var encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();

    return (Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted));
  }

}
```

I am not still begin able to understand where is the bug.

Comment: The following answer is not exactly a duplicate but will probably answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688756/c-sharp-class-without-main-method

Comment: could you post a screenshot of the exception that is displayed in Visual Studio? I'm mainly interested in *what* wants that method.

As to why not use `public` for your entry method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx

Comment: Can you confirm that you are building this through a [Web IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_integrated_development_environment) such as [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)? This error does not occur under normal circumstances, but Google reveals that .NET Fiddle emits it a lot. The C# Language Specification does certainly not require `Main` to publicly accessible.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen even in .Net Fiddle I can't get the error...

Comment: @Thomas No, not with the code of the question, you are right. But if you make a new console project inside .NET Fiddle, and then restrict the access to either `Main` or the class (`Program`) containing it, you can get the quoted message. This message, `Public Main() method is required in a public class`, cannot come from a compliant C# compiler.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution for .NET Fiddle**
Four years after original post ... console compilation on .net Fiddle require that both the class containing the main method and the static main method have to be marked public.

Since execution for the fiddle applications begin with the 'Run' button, not with a command typed at the command line, I guess the 'args' are just ignored. However, command line input can still be accomplished with `Console.ReadLine();`

A simple example I found on an anon fiddle:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            int number;
            string inputData = Console.ReadLine();

            if(int.TryParse(inputData, out number))
            {
                if (number > 0)
                { 
                    Console.WriteLine("You typed " + number + ". This is a postive value");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else if (number < 0) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You typed" + number+ ". This is a negative value");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You typed" + number + " (zero).");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            else
            {
              Console.WriteLine("The input was not a valid integer.");
            }
    }
}
```

Many 'console-ations' for expecting (like the original poster) that .net fiddle works like a console application, hope this helps!